# Changing Silverlight view

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to create a extension from an existing view where I have a list of text controls and in the new project I would like to use this control and change one of these text boxes to a radio button.

Using MVVM makes it easy to use the same code without having duplicated code, but for the XAML view I find no good way to do this change without creating a copy.

Example:

Core project with the main user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication4.MainPage" Name="test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock>
            asdfasdf
            this is a test
            </TextBlock>
            <Button Height="120" Name="asdf" Content="This is a Button">

            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now I have a second project where I want to change the TextBlock to something else.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:core="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication4;assembly=SilverlightApplication4" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
<core:MainPage>
   <!-- how do i change the type of child elements?-->
</core:MainPage>

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution will be to use a ContentControl and bind it to a ViewModel through Caliburn.Micro.

I added an example and code to my other question (below the XAML section): [Project structure for EF/Silverlight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583451/project-structure-for-ef-silverlight-application)